# Make jQuery work with all numbered varients of ID

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I'm coding something in-which certain text appears depending on which li you click. The jQuery I have written works, **but doesn't take into account that all this data is being outputted by a PHP loop**. Is there a way where I can change the jQuery I've written can work for an infinite number of li's rather than only the ones I've specified?

```
$('#selection1').on('click', function() {
   $('.content-block').removeClass('active');
   $('.content-selector').removeClass('active');
   $('#message1').addClass('active');
   $('#selection1').addClass('active');
});

$('#selection2').on('click', function() {
   $('.content-block').removeClass('active');
   $('.content-selector').removeClass('active');
   $('#message2').addClass('active');
   $('#selection2').addClass('active');
});

$('#selection3').on('click', function() {
   $('.content-block').removeClass('active');
   $('.content-selector').removeClass('active');
   $('#message3').addClass('active');
   $('#selection3').addClass('active');
});
```

Comment: You can use class `$('.selection')` or `$('li')`

Comment: Show us the HTML structure.

Comment: you can use a generic class for your elements

Comment: You should really use common classes along with DOM traversal to find related elements instead of incremental `id` attributes (which are an anti-pattern). If you can show us a sample of the HTML we can show you exactly how to do this

Comment: Html structure will really be helpful here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that in jQuery you use selectors from css, so the easiest way to do it would be to cahnge this

```js
$('#selection1').on('click', function() {
```

to this

```js
$('[id^="selection"]').on('click', function() {
```

Which will apply to all elements that has an `id` that starts with "selection".

Also inside the `click` event use variable `this` instead of refering again to `id`.

```js
$('[id^="selection"]').on('click', function() {
    var selection = $(this),
        number = selection.attr("id").substr(9);

    $('.content-block, .content-selector').removeClass('active');

    $('#message' + number).addClass('active');
    selection.addClass('active');
});
```

Comment: Used this one as I could understand the code. Got an "unexpected token" on line three. But I just saw you edited your code to fix that. I had already added the "selection.attr" and it had worked. Great stuff, thank you!

Comment: Yep, my mistake. That's because I copied part of code from my previous approach which I changed and forgot to add `selection.attr...`

Comment: Totally fine. I immediately knew what you were getting at either-way! :)

Answer (score 1):

If you make the buttons, you can add a data-atribute (1,2 or 3), and then add a class to the clicked button like this:

```
$('.buttonClicked').on('click', function() {
   $('.content-block').removeClass('active');
   $('.content-selector').removeClass('active');
   var num = $(this).attr('data-atribute'); //Get the 1,2 or 3 number dynamically
   $('#message'+num).addClass('active');
   $('#selection'+num).addClass('active');
});
```

Comment: you can one better this by doing `$(this).data('atrribute')`

Comment: Yes you're right, but personally I find that .data() doesn't work in some olders version of browsers. That's why I simply use .attr() -- access to the atribute directly

Comment: attr("data-attribute") is the correct way to retrieve static strings. .data can be used to set and get data from the data-store which is not necessarily the same use case: `As of jQuery 1.4.3 HTML 5 data- attributes will be automatically pulled in to jQuery's data object.`

Comment: Thank you for all the help guys! This has been useful!

Answer (score 1):

Use the function like this

```
$('li').on('click', function() {
       var num =  $(this).attr("id").substr(6);
       console.log(num)
       $('.content-block').removeClass('active');
       $('.content-selector').removeClass('active');

       $('#message'+ num).addClass('active');
       $('#selection'+ num).addClass('active');
    });
```

```js
$('li').on('click', function() {
   var num =  $(this).attr("id").substr(6);
   console.log(num)
   $('.content-block').removeClass('active');
   $('.content-selector').removeClass('active');
   
   $('#message'+ num).addClass('active');
   $('#selection'+ num).addClass('active');
});
```

```html
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<ul>
  <li id="select1">
  1
  </li>
  <li id="select2">
  2
  </li>
  <li id="select3">
  3
  </li>
  <li id="select4">
  4
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Really like how this one was coded Nandita. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Thanks for the compliment @CharlieMcShane :)

Answer (score 0):

If you really don't want to change your HTML, you can use jQuery `^=` selector to select every element with an `id` starting with `"selection"`.

```js
$(document).on('click', '[id^="selection"]', function() {
  let id = +this.id.replace('selection',''); //Get the ID value here
  $('.content-block,.content-selector').removeClass('active');
  $('#message'+id).addClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

```css
div{
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: blue;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px;
}

div.active{
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="selection1"></div>
<div id="selection2"></div>
<div id="selection3"></div>
<div id="selection4"></div>
<div id="selection5"></div>

<div id="message1"></div>
<div id="message2"></div>
<div id="message3"></div>
<div id="message4"></div>
<div id="message5"></div>
```

Comment: Yes! I ended up using the ^= selector in the end. Thank you for all your help Zenoo, really appreciate it!